# Align two audios with similar parts

Tags: audio-processing

I have two audios tracks, extracted from two videos.

They sound almost equally except for a few differences.

- Different duration. E.g. first track is 10min length, and second track is 10.5min length because it's stretched.
- First audio has only English voice. Second audio contains English + foreign-language voice, and you can hear both because they're mixed as voiceover. In other words: audio 1 has *Music, Noises, English speech*; audio 2 has *Music, Noises, English speech, Foreign language speech*.
- First and second tracks can differ by its windows, or gaps.
  E.g. first track could be
  *scene 1, gap 1sec, scene 2, gap 1sec, scene 3,*
  and second track could be
  *scene 1, gap 2sec, scene 2, gap 2sec, scene 3.*

I wonder if there are any solutions that could align these two tracks.

That's what I've tried so far:

- Cubase 10.5. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGXkHdzjzMg It doesn't work if tracks have different voices.
- Revoice Pro. Same - doesn't recognize tracks with different voices. Probably doesn't support long audios.

Comment: You mention track 2 is stretched, can you detect a change in pitch between the two audios? (normally a stretched audio clip will decrease in pitch, unless a pitch-preserving algorithm is used)

Comment: Yes pitches are a little different in my case. But I think such calculations would be too approximate, because videos can be long as 40-60 mins. Also because of different gaps between scenes, this method won't work :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) (DTW) is the canonical algorithm for aligning sequences of data that might have slight differences in length/speed. The Python library librosa has a brief tutorial on using it [for music syncronization](https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_music_sync).

There might also be DTW implementations in some graphical audio editors, but I am not familiar with any.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to eliminate the silence gaps between every scene from both audios, so that you are left with only a pair of lists of clean audio clips for each scene.

Then I would recreate both audio signals. The stretched signal would have a constant-length gap between every scene.  The original (non-stretched) signal would have variable gaps between scenes, equal to `[length of constant gap] + [length of stretched scene - length of normal scene]`. This would make every scene start at precisely the same time.

If the gaps between the scenes drop the audio signal to a perfect zero level, detecting and removing the gaps should be trivial.

Otherwise, this could be a little bit tricky (there is usually some DC shift and/or some background noise signal making it a bit difficult to detect "silence" from a time-domain wave representation).
I have successfully used an acoustic energy computation before, to precisely detect where an audio signal begins/ends. This implies sliding a Fourier Transform along the audio (be sure to use a tapered transform, with a Hann or Hamming window). Once you obtain the transform results, you can compute the energy by performing the following computation:

```
E = Sum(r[x]*r[x] + i[x]*i[x])
```

Where x goes from 0 to the [length of your Fourier transform] / 2 - 1, r represents the real part of each result bin, and i the imaginary part of each result bin.

This computation is performed repeatedly while sliding the Fourier transform along the audio, while you record the energy along the way.  **With some proper thresholding, you could probably successfully isolate the audio portions for each scene.**

The length of the Fourier Transform can be small (probably something between the range of 64-256 would suffice, as you don't want a fine frequency resolution, just an estimate of the total energy present at a certain point in time)

Here is an example of a tapered Fourier Transform call ([using the fftw3 library](http://www.fftw.org/)) computing the energy in a range of frequency bands:

```
double EnergyAnalyzer::GetEnergy(array<double>^ audioFrame, Int32 startIndex) {
   if( startIndex + FrameSize > audioFrame->Length ) {
      throw gcnew ArgumentException("The value of startIndex would overflow the array's boundary", "startIndex");
   }
   // Prepare input to the fourier transform.  The signal is tapered using a Hann window
   for( int i = 0; i < FrameSize; i++ ) {
      _pIn[i] = audioFrame[startIndex + i] * _hann[i];
   }
   fftw_execute(_fftPlan);
   double energy = 0.0;
   for( int i = _binStart; i <= _binStop; i++ ) {
      energy += _pOut[i][0] * _pOut[i][0] + _pOut[i][1] * _pOut[i][1];
   }
   return energy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, maybe I'll try this. Or find some software solutions if I get lucky :-)